# Memory management of GTK+ objects using Glade and gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtk, gnome, glade, gtkmm

I am using C++ to create a program using GTK+ and glade. I am concerned about the memory management of the objects that the glade creates. For example, I create a glade file consisting of a window, a button and two entry fields. Then in my C++ code I create an object from that file and get a pointer to that window. My question is, do I have to safely deallocate the window object when I am done? If not, why do I not have to? Below is a sample of my code...

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "MattWindow.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void buttonpush();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //This line initializes the GTK+ system
    Gtk::Main kit(argc,argv);

    //Declare a pointer to a window
    Gtk::Window* window = 0;

    try
    {
        //Load the glade file
        Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("layout.glade");

        Assign window to point to the window object
        builder->get_widget("window1",window);
        window->show();
    }
    catch(Gtk::BuilderError& e)
    {
        cout<<e.what();
    }

    //Start everything up
    Gtk::Main::run();



    //Who destroys the object that window is currently pointing to?

    return 0;
}

void buttonpush()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [GTK+ reference manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html):

> A GtkBuilder holds a reference to all objects that it has constructed
>   and drops these references when it is finalized. This finalization can
>   cause the destruction of non-widget objects or widgets which are not
>   contained in a toplevel window. For toplevel windows constructed by a
>   builder, it is the responsibility of the user to call
>   gtk_widget_destroy() to get rid of them and all the widgets they
>   contain.
>
> The functions gtk_builder_get_object() and gtk_builder_get_objects()
>   can be used to access the widgets in the interface by the names
>   assigned to them inside the UI description. Toplevel windows returned
>   by these functions will stay around until the user explicitly destroys
>   them with gtk_widget_destroy(). Other widgets will either be part of a
>   larger hierarchy constructed by the builder (in which case you should
>   not have to worry about their lifecycle), or without a parent, in
>   which case they have to be added to some container to make use of
>   them. Non-widget objects need to be reffed with g_object_ref() to keep
>   them beyond the lifespan of the builder.

To answer your question: yes, you should manually destroy the window when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

GTK widgets are reference counted. When you close or destroy your window, it will release its last reference and be deallocated. (Although I believe the builder also holds a reference - but that should be released when the builder is destroyed.)